# Mark all the columns after the first occurrence of an event as NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to mark all the columns after the first occurrence of an event(ONE-OFF) as NaN in pandas dataframe

Note: There can be multiple rows in this df and ONE-OFF can appear at any column or may not appear at all

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         1: {'15': 'Normal'},
         2: {'15': 'Normal'},
         3: {'15': 'Normal'},
         4: {'15': 'ONE-OFF'},
         5: {'15': 'Normal'},
         6: {'15': 'Normal'},
    }
)
```

All columns for this row should be NaN after first occurrence of ONE-OFF

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         1: {'15': 'Normal'},
         2: {'15': 'Normal'},
         3: {'15': 'Normal'},
         4: {'15': 'ONE-OFF'},
         5: {'15': np.nan},
         6: {'15': np.nan},
    }
)
```

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: what should happen if you have several ONE-OFF in a row?

Answer (score 0):

Compare values and use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`DataFrame.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) for mask and replace `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace values after first matched value per rows separately:

```
print (input_df)
         1        2       3        4       5        6
0   Normal   Normal  Normal  ONE-OFF  Normal   Normal
1  ONE-OFF   Normal  Normal   Normal  Normal   Normal
2   Normal   Normal  Normal  ONE-OFF  Normal   Normal
3   Normal  ONE-OFF  Normal   Normal  Normal   Normal
4   Normal   Normal  Normal   Normal  Normal  ONE-OFF

df = input_df.mask(input_df.shift(axis=1).eq('ONE-OFF').cummax(axis=1))
print (df)
         1        2       3        4       5        6
0   Normal   Normal  Normal  ONE-OFF     NaN      NaN
1  ONE-OFF      NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2   Normal   Normal  Normal  ONE-OFF     NaN      NaN
3   Normal  ONE-OFF     NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
4   Normal   Normal  Normal   Normal  Normal  ONE-OFF
```

If need set all columns by first occurncy in any column use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for mask:

```
m = input_df.shift(axis=1).eq('ONE-OFF').cummax(axis=1).any()

input_df.loc[:, m] = np.nan
print (input_df)
         1    2    3    4    5    6
0   Normal  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  ONE-OFF  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   Normal  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   Normal  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   Normal  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```